# Windows Debug Api - Detaching not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, debugging

I'm running my event loop in a thread that is created on attaching to target process.
What I did before to detach was simply calling a function that would clear the debug and call DebugSetProcessKillOnExit etc. but getting bad return values I figured they must be called from the thread that I created. So I did, no errors now but the target process simply exits when I exit/detach myself.

At the moment I check for a bool in the event loop to check if I should detach (any better solutions?) and then do the following:

```
pEng->ClearHardwareBreakpoints();
DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(FALSE);
ContinueDebugEvent(pEng->pId, pEng->tId, DBG_CONTINUE); 
DebugActiveProcessStop(pEng->pId);

return 0;
```

ClearHardwareBreakpoints suspends the target thread, calls GetThreadContext with CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS and removes the debug registers with SetThreadContext and resuming the thread.

So, as I said, the problem is that the debugged process exits with my process as well, as if the detaching did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Break it down to the smallest possible problem.  Comment out things then slowly add them back until the issue occurs.  At least that will help narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error: I was exiting my program before the thread had done its part (detaching).